# make a d.ts file to only override exported enum and return all other original defs?

Tags: typescript, react-native-paper, typescript-definitions

I am using ReactNativePaper and their fonts/typography unfortunately is not playing along well with custom named text variants.

I thought I would try to extend or override the [MD3TypescaleKey](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/aebeabd8769988b17bb56b0f5673f252e1bda0d9/src/types.tsx#L145) by making a new `react-native-paper.d.ts` file in the root of my project:

```
import 'react-native-paper';

declare module 'react-native-paper' {
    export const enum MD3TypescaleKey {
        default = 'default',

        bodyXS = 'bodyXS',
        bodySmall = 'bodySmall',
        bodyMedium = 'bodyMedium',
        bodyLarge = 'bodyLarge',

        bodyXSBold = 'bodyXSBold',
        bodySmallBold = 'bodySmallBold',
        bodyMediumBold = 'bodyMediumBold',
        bodyLargeBold = 'bodyLargeBold',

        titleXS = 'titleXS',
        titleSmall = 'titleSmall',
        titleMedium = 'titleMedium',
        titlelarge = 'titlelarge',

        headlineXS = 'headlineXS',
        headlineSmall = 'headlineSmall',
        headlineMedium = 'headlineMedium',
        headlineLarge = 'headlineLarge',
        headlineXL = 'headlineXL',

        displaySmall = 'displaySmall',
        displayMedium = 'displayMedium',
        displayLarge = 'displayLarge',

        button = 'button',

        inputLabel = 'inputLabel',
    }
}
```

I am not sure if because an enum, but now all other references to the library, such as `import { Card } from 'react-native-paper'` are failing due to `Card` not being exported:

> Module '"react-native-paper"' has no exported member 'Card'.ts(2305)

I have solved this before from react-native-elements, but it was an interface, not an enum.

Any ideas?